# Structure operation-input is missing a field "spec"

Tags: spring-webclient, vcenter, apache-httpclient-5.x

I'm trying to generate a Support bundle using the vCenter REST API using Spring's WebClient. When I trigger the bundle creation using cURL (even faking the headers to simulate what Java sends), everything works fine:

```
$ curl -A "Apache-HttpAsyncClient/5.1 (Java/14.0.2)" -X POST 'https://vcenter.internal.system:443/api/appliance/support-bundle?vmw-task=true' -H 'vmware-api-session-id: 4d63eec20a2fd6baadfef6ba9c308f92' -H 'Content-type: application/json' -d '{ "components": { "VirtualAppliance": [ "ApplianceManagement", "Rhttpproxy" ] }, "description": "bundle", "partition": "" }' --insecure
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   204    0    74  100   130    217    382 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   601"8459589f-0bcc-4a88-b579-8996c97c66aa:com.vmware.appliance.support_bundle"
```

When I do the same from the WebClient, I get a strange HTTP 400 error:

```json
{
    "error_type": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "messages": [
        {
            "args": [
                "operation-input",
                "spec"
            ],
            "default_message": "Structure operation-input is missing a field \"spec\"",
            "id": "vapi.data.structure.field.missing"
        }
    ]
}
```

By adding some verbose logging to both cURL and the Apache's HTTP Client, I see that the body and headers sent are the same, so this is quite a mystery.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question since I could not find anything even remotely related to the problem anywhere on the web. The solution was to force the HTTP Client to use HTTP 1.1

```java
HttpAsyncClientBuilder clientBuilder = HttpAsyncClients.custom();
clientBuilder.setVersionPolicy(HttpVersionPolicy.FORCE_HTTP_1);
CloseableHttpAsyncClient client = clientBuilder.build();
```

After staring at the raw data of requests and responses, I noticed that cURL sends the headers in plain text while the Apache HTTP Client apparently compresses them. I suspect that there is some buggy behavior on the vCenter's side either in the HTTP header decompression, or in the handling of HTTP/2 in general.